# android: Expandable listview going inside tablayout

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout, collapsable

i have a coordinator layout with collapsable toolbar and below it i have a tablayout and a viewpager and the viewpager contains an expandable listview. When the toolbar collapses the viewpager goes inside the tablayout even if i have specified margins. I have attached links to images below.
Any help is appreciated. Pls help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki0ZG.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEome.png

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout_asset"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_asset"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingtoolbar_asset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout_charts_asset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager_charts_asset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView_dots_asset"
                android:paddingTop="0dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_dots_asset"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
                android:src="@drawable/united1"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_layout_asset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier=".11">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_layout_asset"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Quila"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview_asset"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_asset"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager_asset"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_asset"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/tab_color"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/frame_layout_asset"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    app:title="">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="@dimen/image_final_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_final_width" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Bank Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout_asset"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:background="@color/tab_color"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar_asset"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" />

<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/newUser"
    app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
    app:finalYPosition="2dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.aswin.AvatarImageBehavior"
    app:startHeight="2dp"
    app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
    app:startXPosition="2dp" />
```

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expandable_listview"
        android:divider="@color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="top">
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can u paste you layout file here

Comment: have uploaded the layout files.